# Receiving a request with no accessible data. ActionDispatcher, therefore, extracts no usable params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, cors, mime-types, middleware

I'm getting a CORS POST request via OPTIONS sent to my app. It has no content-type set for the request.

It successfully gets to the right Controller action, but there is no accessible data. If I type `params`, there is nothing I can touch.

I did, however, discover that if I created Rack Middleware, and read the `env['rack.input']`, I could find all the data in the request I was looking for. So I wrote this :

```
env['CONTENT_TYPE'] = 'application/js'
rack_input = env['rack.input'].read
params = CGI::parse(rack_input).to_json
env['rack.input']   = StringIO.new params
env['rack.input'].rewind
status, headers, response = @app.call env
```

And magically, now in my controller, I can type `params` and see that ActionDispatcher successfully extracted the key/values from the request and make them accessible in my controller.

There's something suspicious about this. Is there are more appropriate way to extract OPTIONS requests and their respective data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OPTIONS call should not deal with data at all. It's a preflighted request to determine which actions are allowed using when using CORS.

RFC:
http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.14.7

The call will return with the allowed CORS HTTP verbs and a POST request should follow right after if POSTs are allowed on the server.

Comment: So then do I need to initiate a POST request back to its origin? In most of the tutorials I've found, they seem to just set their headers as accepting ( which is what I do ), but no further call is sent.

Comment: You might need to post your Javascript code here so we can see if there's anything wrong with it. My CORS POST requests always make an OPTIONS call first, then follows up with a POST. Maybe your server isn't responding to the OPTIONS request properly.

A good way to set those up is with this rack middleware. https://github.com/cyu/rack-cors